# After creating indexes in neo4j, "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException" occurs when operating "findNode" function with java api

Tags: java, neo4j

I have stored many nodes in neo4j database where most nodes with **PERSON** label may have the property **"chinese_name"** but some may not. After I created an index on this property with **Cypher-shell**, I got the exception while getting nodes by the label and the property with Java API. After I deleted the index, it worked well. Here are the codes:

```
private static final File DB_PATH = new File("/home/charlie/Projects/databases/neo4j_demo.db");
private static GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
public static void testGetNode() {
    graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
    registerShutdownHook(graphDb);
    try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()){
        ResourceIterator<Node> iter = graphDb.findNodes(KgEnum.KgLabel.PERSON, "chinese_name", "刘德华");
        if (iter.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("got one or more nodes");
        } else {
            System.out.println("no node got");
        }
        tx.success();
    } finally {
        graphDb.shutdown();
    }
}
```

And the exception stack trace is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.AbstractSwallowingIndexProxy.newReader(AbstractSwallowingIndexProxy.java:110)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.FlippableIndexProxy.newReader(FlippableIndexProxy.java:308)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.AbstractDelegatingIndexProxy.newReader(AbstractDelegatingIndexProxy.java:116)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.IndexReaderFactory$Caching.newUnCachedReader(IndexReaderFactory.java:70)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.IndexReaderFactory$Caching.newReader(IndexReaderFactory.java:60)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.StoreStatement.getIndexReader(StoreStatement.java:256)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.newapi.AllStoreHolder.indexReader(AllStoreHolder.java:255)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.newapi.Read.nodeIndexSeek(Read.java:113)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.nodesByLabelAndProperty(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:718)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.findNodes(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:593)
at Test.testGetNode(Test.java:65)
at Test.main(Test.java:24)
```

Now I have to delete all the indexes and run my code. But why does this exception happen?